# Accuracy of a Normal Approximation for a Poisson random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

compute bound on accuracy of a normal approximation for a poisson random variable with mean 100?

I understand what the question is trying to ask me but I have no idea how to approach it and solve it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "Accuracy" in which sense?

Comment: Because the Poisson distribution is discrete, it is sometimes useful to use the continuous normal distribution as an approximation. So accuracy just means to how well does the normal distribution approximates  for discrete poisson distribution I am guessing

Comment: Which measure of the quality of the approximation do you wish to consider? There are several of them, and they are not equivalent...

Comment: oh good point, its using Stein-Chen Method

Comment: This is not a measure of closeness.

Comment: Well I don't know then. This is what is given to us. No more info is provided. So I'm guessing we can use which ever measure we please but I was guessing it would be something involving Stein's Method